# How to set a derived property to lower case in Grails/GORM?

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm

This is a newbie question -- thank you for your help. I wanted to set a derived property to lower case in my domain model. Did some search (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#ormdsl plus some other) and I thought the following would work (note: `nameLowerCase formula: 'LOWER(NAME)'`) ...

```
class Item {
    String name
    String nameLowerCase

    static constraints = {
        name(blank: false)
        nameLowerCase(blank: false, unique: true)
    }

    static mapping = {
        nameLowerCase formula: 'LOWER(NAME)'
        sort nameLowerCase: "asc"
    }
}
```

However, when I do ...

```
new Item(name: 'A').save(failOnError: true)
new Item(name: 'c').save(failOnError: true)
new Item(name: 'B').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

println Item.list().nameLowerCase
```

I was expecting it to print `[a, b, c]` (turning to lower case in addition to the sorting), but it prints `[null, null, null]`, and I am unable to figure out why.

What am I doing wrong? Or, is there any other way I can achieve the lower case in my domain class itself for `nameLowerCase` irrespective of what is passed for the `name` (other than using the formula in mapping)? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this

```
def beforeInsert() {
    nameLowerCase = name.toLowerCase()
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    nameLowerCase = name.toLowerCase()
}
```

and remove this

```
nameLowerCase formula: 'LOWER(NAME)'
```

and Enjoy..

Comment: Wow, thank you Abdullah ... you saved my day! I had struggled to get this one work. One minor point ... in addition to your recommendations, I had to make 'nullable: true' instead of 'blank: false' for the 'nameLowerCase' in the constraints, and it worked as expected. Thank you very much!

Comment: With all the changes mentioned above, I was still having some issue with validating the uniqueness constraint for the 'nameLowerCase' (during integration testing). Took me a while to figure out that I needed to add another method in the 'Item' domain class as follows (very similar to Abdullah's): `def beforeValidate(){nameLowerCase = name.toLowerCase()}`. And it worked now!

Answer (score 3):

I think storing the same data in the database is a bad idea.
It's better to do it this way:

```
class Item {
    static transients = ['nameLoweCase']
    String name

    String getNameLowerCase(){
       name.toLowerCase() 
    }

    static constraints = {
       name blank: false
    }
}
```

And in the controller:

```
class SomeController{
     def show(Long id){
        def item = Item.get(id)
        item.nameLowerCase // name in lower case
     }
}
```

'transient' defines a list of property names that should not be persisted to the database ([more about it](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.3/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html)).

Comment: Thank you @user2980104! I believe I understand your point, and it makes sense. I like both the answers, @Abdullah's answer tells me how to do what exactly I wanted to do, and yours tells me a better approach to what I wanted to do. Also thanks for the 'more about it' link, which enforces what you just said!

Comment: Gave some more thoughts to it. If I go Anjey's route, I won't be able to specify the 'unique: true' constraint to 'nameLowerCase' (or, can I?), which is required in my case. However, I can constraint the 'name' to be unique, but that will let cases like 'new Item(name: "A")' and 'new Item(name: "a")' slip through (which I do not want). However, if I go Abdullah's route, I am able to specify the 'unique: true' constraint to 'nameLowerCase' easily. So given my requirement of constraining 'nameLowerCase' to be unique, Abdullah's route seems preferable. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yep - you can't use 'unique' constraint to 'nameLowerCase'. In this case I advice you to use custom constraint validator : name blank: false, validator: `{ val, obj ->
def user = User.findByNameLike(val) 
return !user || obj.id == user.id })`
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Anjey. I spent quite some time trying to implement the custom constraint validator you have given above, but could not get it to work (most likely because of my inexperience with the whole thing). I am having better luck with Abdullah's approach.